# Installing/Using Ruby 2.x and Qt 5

Tags: ruby, windows, qt

Are there simple ways to install and use Qt for using qt-ruby on my Windows 7 (64bit) computer? Which steps do I have to take for installing Qt for using it with Ruby? Do I have to install the [Qt SDK](http://qt-project.org/resources/getting_started) for the C++ environment? Or is it easier another way?

My goal is to write Qt-Ruby-Code from Emacs and then compile it using MinGW/MSys.

Current Info:

- I only found bindings for Qt 4.xx at [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=qt) and at the [KDE Korundum page](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my computer but as far as I can remember https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings is about your only choice. And the qt build they recommend at http://qt.nokia.com/ times out for me. :( What exactly are you trying to do with those specific version requirements?